# How to separate a image name from array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

Im having a image array which i retrieved from database, I want to retrieve the name of images in image array,i tried this ,its not working,

```
  - (NSString *)convertToDisplayName
 {
  NSMutableString *displayName = [[name mutableCopy] autorelease];
  [displayName replaceOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""
  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, displayName.length)];
  [displayName replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "
  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, displayName.length)];
  return displayName;
 }
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance?

Comment: could you provide an example of your input data and desired output?

Comment: What's the array format?

Comment: No answer working on my previous question ,Will you @RandeepSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even smaller,

```
- (NSString *) convertToDisplayName:(NSString *) actual
{
    return [[actual stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
}

 NSLog("@Result : %@",[self convertToDisplayName:@"test_file.png"]);
```

> Result : test file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code lines:

```
- (NSString *)convertToDisplayName
 {
  NSMutableString *displayName = [[name mutableCopy] autorelease];
  [displayName replaceOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""
  options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, displayName.length)];
  [displayName replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "
  options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, displayName.length)];
  return displayName;
 }
```